Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')" error in EAS iOS build Fastlane
I’m having trouble with an issue that I haven’t been able to resolve. I’m using Expo and everything works perfectly fine locally, even when running with --no-dev --minify. However, when I try to build for iOS using EAS (eas build --platform ios), I consistently get this error during the Fastlane Expo stage, specifically in the bundling phase:
❌ error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind') ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED ** ▸ The following build commands failed: ▸ PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/343Football-ctjmsizzoghufiftziocteygetsx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/343Football/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/343Football.build/Release-iphoneos/343Football.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target '343Football' from project '343Football') ▸ (1 failure)
Locally, I’ve searched my codebase for any uses of .bind() but only found it in the node_modules, so I’m not sure where the error is coming from. I’ve tried clearing caches (expo start -c and eas build --clear-cache), but the issue persists only during the EAS build.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any advice on how I can narrow down where this error is coming from? Are there additional steps I can take to debug this, given that I can't reproduce the error locally?

I ended up running npx expo-doctor@latest and that revealed some issues related to metro resolutions and overrides. I fixed them and was able to build without any more errors
